# display the 1st variable in a tuple in PowerShell

Tags: arraylist, indexing, powershell-3.0

I want to set the Netadapter "Roaming aggressiveness" value to "lowest" on all of our computers.

The wifi chips vary from one computer to another so that "Roaming aggressiveness" lowest value on on computer may display as "**1.Lowest**" vs another that displays as "**1. Lowest**" vs another with "**1 - Lowest**" and who knows what other variations.

Because of this, the below script does not work for ALL of our computers when trying to set them all to lowest roaming aggressiveness.

`Set-NetadapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -DisplayName "Roaming aggressiveness" -DisplayValue "1.Lowest"`

To get around this, I want to replace the "1.Lowest" instead to a variable that references the 1st DisplayValue without needing to know the actual name. I just know the 1st item is always the lowest option.

I am able to get the ValidDisplayValues into a variable called $RoamOptions:

```
$RoamOptions = Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty Wi-Fi -DisplayName *Roam* | ft ValidDisplayValues
```

The result of this on a sample computer is

```
ValidDisplayValues
------------------
{1. Lowest, 2. Medium-low, 3. Medium, 4. Medium-High...}
```

How do I create a variable $LowestOption that grabs the 1st item in the list so I can then reference it as follows so it would work for all of our computers?

`Set-NetadapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi" -DisplayName "Roaming aggressiveness" -DisplayValue $LowestOption`

Hope that makes sense.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the format-table and use this syntax.

```
PS> $x = (Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty "*Wi-Fi" -DisplayName *Roam*).ValidDisplayValues

PS> $x.count
5

PS> $x[0]
1. Lowest

PS>
```

Note: the * in front of Wi-Fi is because mine has been renamed. Might be good to use incase yours is likewise.

Comment: THANK YOU so much, @RetiredGeek. That works. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer by checking the Check Mark so others know the problem is solved.